# Insert Javascript Code into HTML from PHP response

Tags: javascript, php, html, ajax

Hi I am trying to insert a JavaScript code in my HTML document using the following AJAX-PHP  code inside the function called `exJS()`, following is the content of the function `exJS()`

```
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php", false);
xmlhttp.send();
```

This what `ajax.php` is

```
<?php
  echo '<script language="javascript">
           alert("Hello World");
           var testVAR = "Hello World";
       </script>';
?>
```

Now whenever I execute this function `exJS()` the alert doesn't work but when I view the source code using F12 and see the contents of the `div#myDiv"` I see that the entire script is embedded inside the `div` but still the JavaScript for some reason is not getting registered.

I even tried accessing the JavaScript variable `testVAR`, I see the variable in the source code when I hit F12 but when I try to access that variable I get an error, that no such variable is defined.

Please note that it is simple example so there is no error and that the PHP code is echoing just fine, all the contents are returned from the PHP code, when I view the code and see what are the content of the `div` element the entire PHP echo content is present there but still not executing.

Also if I open the `ajax.php` file directly it works fine, I mean I get the alert message, but the same thing doesn't happen when I execute the function `jsEx()` the JavaScript code gets inserted into `myDiv` but nothing happens, no alert.

Comment: This too convoluted: either fetch your remote script in original DOM via `<script src="yourscript.js"></script>`, or use [`jQuery.getScript`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/) for instance.

Comment: No I can't do it like that, my problem is much more complex but to keep things simple I have used a simple question to relate to my actual problem

Comment: I need to find a solution of executing JavaScript code returned by a PHP file using AJAX

Comment: Just return the data you need as JSON, and keep the .js sources clean without messing with PHP.

Comment: can you give me an example on how to do this

Comment: The whole web is full of examples, search for `json_encode()` [server side] and `jQuery.getJSON()` [client side] ^^

Answer (score 1):

BTW jQuery has a specific AJAX function to get a script: http://api.jquery.com/jquery.getscript/

If you want to avoid jQuery a workaround would be to make it so you echo an iframe and from that Iframe you link to the PHP generating the actual Javascript.

E.G. a sample ajax.php

```
   if( isset($_GET['getscript']) ){
       header('Content-type: application/javascript'); #or header('Content-type: text/javascript');
       echo 'alert("The script is working.")';

       exit;

   }

   echo '<iframe src="ajax.php?getscript=1" frameborder="0"/>';
?>
```

Comment: If your claim that "some browsers might block javascript loaded via ajax", then how the hell would jQuery be able to do it? ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

tested in my `WAMP` (win 7, php 5.4) & works fine in `IE11`,`Chrome`,`Safari`,`FireFox` and `Opera` (I don't have any other ;-) )

`index.html`:

```
<head>
<title>Testing DYNAMIC JS</title>
<script type="text/javascript">

function exJS(){
var xmlhttp;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
{// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else
{// code for IE6, IE5
 xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
{
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
    var script = document.createElement('script');
    script.onload = function() {
    // alert("Script loaded and ready");
    };
    script.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");
    script.text = xmlhttp.responseText;
    document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0].appendChild(script);
}
}
xmlhttp.open("GET","ajax.php", false);
xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>
</head>
<body onload="exJS();">
</body>
</html>
```

in `ajax.php` try:

```
<?php
  echo 'alert("Hello World"); var testVAR = "Hello World";';
?>
```

if you want to run script from within a `div`:

use:

`javaScript`:

```
if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
{
var MyDiv=document.getElementById("myDiv");
var arr = MyDiv.getElementsByTagName('script');
for (var n = 0; n < arr.length; n++)
    eval(arr[n].innerHTML);
}
```

and `php`:

```
<?php
  echo '<script language="javascript">
           alert("Hello World");
           var testVAR = "Hello World";
       </script>';
?>
```

hope it'll help you.